# That’s the ridge through there

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

[image]

The two pictures are screenshots taken from a FPS game.

When I came to this, one of the marines beside me said to me, "**That’s the ridge through there**. We’ll buy you as much time as we can. See you at the victory parade, Sergeant."

Does he mean that you need to creep under the rock and get to the ridge, or the ridge is the rock ahead and you'll have to creep through it?

Why not say "There’s the ridge through there"? It seems clearer.

Comment: I can't see your images, so I'm just guessing, but when someone says "it's through there" it usually means you have to go down a passage, or through an opening to get to the location they're talking about. If I say "The conference room is through there" and I point in the direction of a door, I'm indicating you should go through the door to get to it.

Comment: Did my images fail to come out? I ask because I cannot see them, either. I've condensed them to a less size. @ColleenV

Comment: I tried to go directly to the imgur URL, and couldn't see them that way either so I assumed it was an issue with my browser, or that maybe you accidentally had the permissions set to private or went over your bandwidth limit.

Comment: I've reformatted them to JPEG and uploaded em. Seems you were right about it. @ColleenV

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see the images, I'm fairly certain **"That's the ridge through there"** means that you should crouch and go under the rock to get to the location. Typically a ridge is a larger terrain feature than that rock, especially in the context of a military action, and "through there" would mean that you have to go through an opening or passageway.

It might have been clearer to say **"The ridge is through there"** but it's common for a native speaker to say "That's it over there" if he or she was guiding you to a location.